# Div element jumping to the top of page despite written inside another section and another div

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I recently ran into a problem that has got me puzzled. It may be just due to having tunnel vision after learning to code essentially by trial and error, but I have a div (supposed to be a single color shape background for some text) and even thought it is positioned in the right html section and (super)div, it just does not show up where I would expect it to, but rather jumps all the way to the top of the page.

Would you have any suggestions?

```css
.third-section .problematic-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0%;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 340px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="first-section">
  ...
</section>
... ... ...
<section class="third-section">
  <div>
    <div class="problematic-div"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing `position: relative;` in one of the parents.
Thanks to this property the **absoulte** child components will be positioned **relatively** to it, so if you add `position: relative;` to the *.third-section* class, the *.problematic-div* will position itself on top of this section.